# Интерпретатор Python ведет себя странно. ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python-3.x, input, pycharm

[Это типичное поведение для PyCharm? Тот же код работает в Wing 101 без нареканий. Помогите разобраться в сути данной ошибки, прикладываю скриншоты из PyCharm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MUKU.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по ссылке доступен ещё один скриншот с другим кодом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Меня интересует почему PyCharm распознает нормально первый int(input()), а второй уже как ' ' и  выдает ошибку ValueError

Comment: Почитайте другие вопросы на эту тему тут. Если коротко - это баг PyCharm. Вот и весь "почему":-)

Comment: Какой неприятный баг) Почитал, ответ нашел.